# How upgrade socket.io timeout delay?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, fs

Forgive my bad english , ^^Loo^^.

I m working on a project with socket.Io.
When i upload image , i encode image in base64 then send it to socket.io

FS extra ( https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra ) permits me to create physical image on dsk.

My upload work correctly when i upload litte image , but when the image size is moore 400Ko , socket.io (timeout) , do nott perform all task.
So how can i up the socket.io timeout delay

Nb : on local (Core I5 DELL), i don't have that problem , but on my vps ( just 1GO ram ) this problem occur , is it due to my ram ?

Comment: Another way to solve your problem could be changing the whole process of uploading something to your node.js server. You could send the file in chunk of say 50Ko, that way the socket will never timeout I suppose.
Anyway [this](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object)) seems to be what your looking for

Comment: Thanks  for your advice , but , i tried the same princip and used expressJs middleware ( multer) , but the upload is still very slow , it take 1 min to upload an image of 400KO.

Comment: Isn't your connection the problem? Is it uploading at max upload speed of your Internet connection?

Comment: Hy Maxime,
No , i don't think its due to my internet connection because , i tried an upload on another connection (at a friend home)  , but it is still slow .
Finally , i gave up , and i m tring recode my app using MongoDb , i wish , the upload will be moore quick.
may you have nice week end

Comment: Could you show us what's the code behind your problem ? That's the only way we can find what's possibly wrong there